# Using Feature Dataset with ReplaceDataSource gives ValueError: Layer: Unexpected error

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, feature-dataset, valueerror

I'm attempting to replace the data source of a unsourced layer with a mxd. The issue I'm having is that the Featureclass "APPL" is contained within a Feature Dataset. When the feature class is outside of the data set the code below works perfectly.

```
   workspace = output + "\\PlanningSession.gdb\\DIDs" ## Dataset

   lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"DAB_APPL", df)[0]
   lyr.replaceDataSource(workspace, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", "APPL")
```

The error received can be found below:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Q:\Admin\Python_Scripts\Tools\PlanningSession\Script\PlanningSession.py", line 356, in <module>
        lyr.replaceDataSource(workspace, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", "APPL")
      File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
        return fn(*args, **kw)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\_mapping.py", line 681, in replaceDataSource
        return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.replaceDataSource(*gp_fixargs((workspace_path, workspace_type, dataset_name, validate),True)))
    ValueError: Layer: Unexpected error

    Failed to execute (PlanningSession).
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution to my problem. Instead of referencing the dataset within the geodatabase, simply reference the geodatabase.

For example:

```
    # workspace = output + "\\PlanningSession.gdb\\DIDs" ## Referencing the Feature Dataset
    workspace = output + "\\PlanningSession.gdb" ## Referencing the GDB

    lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"DAB_APPL", df)[0]
    lyr.replaceDataSource(workspace, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", "APPL")
```